# wordpress on subdomain and directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I installed wordpress on /var/vwww/blog accessible from blog.example.net

this works fine and perfectly

Then, I also like it to be accessible from www.example.net/blog

As result, firstly, I modify my apache vhost entry to do alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html    
Alias /blog /var/vwww/blog
</VirtualHost>
```

Secondly, i modify /var/vwww/blog/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Last, I modify my wordpress wp-config.php

```
define('BASE_BLOG_URL', 'http://www.example.net/blog');
define('BASE_SITE_URL', 'http://example.net');
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.net/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.net/blog');
```

It works for url like:

- blog.example.net
- www.example.net/blog
- www.example.net/blog/article-slug

but not for

- blog.example.net/article-slug

The above url was working previously, but now I got error 500. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of redirecting one to the other?

Comment: historical reason, most seo and internal link sharing was already done using blog.example.net/article-slug

then now the requirement ask to change to example.net/blog/article-slug and expect both working same time

Comment: Wouldn't a redirect suffice, though? You can still just hit the old URL and will get redirected to the content. I've seen canonical-tag-configurations break multiple times and people ended up with DC in google.
Anyhow, do you have access to the error logs to see what the actual error is?

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/blog/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```